# Is this a valid for this set to not be a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

That's from the Hoffman and Kunze linear algebra book.

In this case I considered that $f(x)=x^2$ satisfies the condition and is therefore in the set, because $f(x^2)=(x^2)^2=(f(x))^2$.

Then I used the fact that if this set is a subspace, then for every $f$ in the set $cf$ must be in the set.

However, for $c=2$, and for $f(x)=x^2$, we have that $2f(x)=2x^2$ is not in the set, because   $2f(x^2)=2(x^2)^2=2x^4$ but $(2f(x))^2=4x^4$ and the condition of the set is not satisfied.

Therefore this set is not a subspace of $V$.

Is this solution correct ?

Comment: **Hint :** The constant function equal to $1$ belongs to the subset, but not the constant function equal to $2$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That is essentially the same as what is written in the post. Both approaches give the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method :

Take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=1.$ Let $h(x)= f(x)+g(x)= x+1.$ Both $f$ and $g$ are in  the given set but not $h,$ as $$h(x^2) = x^2 + 1 \ne (x+1)^2 = h(x)^2. $$

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct.

All you need to know is that there exists a function $f  \ne 0$ which satisfies (a). You took $f(x) = x^2$, but all monomials $f(x) = x^n$, $n = 0,1 ,2 , \ldots$, have this property: $f(x^2) = (x^2)^n = x^{2n} = (x^n)^2 = f(x)^2$.

Since $f \ne 0$, there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb  R$ such that $f(x_0) \ne 0$. For $c \ne 0, 1$ we get
$$(c \cdot f)(x_0^2) = c \cdot f(x_0^2) = c \cdot f(x_0)^2 \ne c^2 \cdot f(x_0)^2 = (c \cdot f)(x_0)^2 ,$$
thus $c \cdot f$ does not satisfy (a).